# How to create a immutable class when a mutable member is singleton

Tags: java, singleton, immutability

Can be create immutable class when a mutable member is singletone where we can not do cloning or copy constructor?

Comment: I don't get it, immutable class by definition doesn't have any mutable members.

Comment: Suppose there is a Date field which is mutable

Comment: I need more details.  Please post some code, preferably (1) the class X you want to be immutable; (2) a mutable member Y of that class, that you can't clone or copy; (3) specifically _how_ you want X to be immutable, focusing on how that relates to Y.  Immutability isn't really a Java concept--there's nothing in the language that cares whether a class is immutable or not.  So you'll need to explain what _you_ mean by immutable, in this context.

Comment: Get the state you want from the singleton, and copy it to another immutable object.

Comment: @KumarAbhishek So you mean a class that is *effectively immutable* not *immutable* those are somehow different things. And as ajb mentioned, code would help

Comment: Not entirely sure whether I get the question right but you could of course override the clone method and return an exception when attempted and make the class final so that constructors and methods can't be overriden.